# Bounce <nobody@gmail.com> Gmail API sending failure

Tags: php, email, gmail-api, send, email-bounces

I'm trying to send emails with the google API. I'm able to read emails, authenticate with oath using a `client_secret.json` file per the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php) instructions. I've almost got sending emails working, but am unable to send successfully.

My email is bouncing and I'm unable to specify the email I'm sending to (hence the `nobody@gmail.com` address).

Code here bellow works for the most part. I've commented out the parts that work: (reading emails).

**Code:**

```
<?php
require 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';

define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Gmail API Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/gmail-api-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', 'client_secret.json');
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
  Google_Service_Gmail::MAIL_GOOGLE_COM,
  Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_COMPOSE)
));

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient() {
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
  $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
  $client->setAuthConfigFile(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
  $client->setAccessType('offline');

  // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
  $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
  if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
    $accessToken = file_get_contents($credentialsPath);
  } else {
    // Request authorization from the user.
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
    print 'Enter verification code: ';
    $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

    // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
    $accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);

    // Store the credentials to disk.
    if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
      mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $accessToken);
    printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
  }
  $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

  // Refresh the token if it's expired.
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->refreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $client->getAccessToken());
  }
  return $client;
}

/**
 * Expands the home directory alias '~' to the full path.
 * @param string $path the path to expand.
 * @return string the expanded path.
 */
function expandHomeDirectory($path) {
  $homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
  if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
    $homeDirectory = getenv("HOMEDRIVE") . getenv("HOMEPATH");
  }
  return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
}

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);


$msg = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message(); 
$mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode("TEST MESSAGE OR SOMETHING"), '+/', '-_'), '=');
$msg->setRaw($mime); 

// Print the labels in the user's account.
$userId = 'me';

function sendMessage($service, $userId, $message) {
  try {
    $message = $service->users_messages->send($userId, $message);
    print 'Message with ID: ' . $message->getId() . ' sent.';
    // <----------- GET'S HERE AND THIS WORKS
    return $message;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }
}

try {
    sendMessage($service, $userId, $msg); 
} catch (Exception $Ex ) {
    echo $Ex->getMessage(); 
}
```

**Email Response** (In my Gmail inbox)**:**

```
An error occurred. Your message was not sent.

TEST MESSAGE OR SOMETHING Date: Tue, 21 Jul 2015 14:51:12 -0700 Message-Id: <
```

I'm not sure how to even specify the destination address, like `personimsendingto@gmail.com`. I couldn't really find much in the way of documentation. If someone could help me out or point me in the right direction, I'd be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put an entire RFC822 email message in the raw field.  So where you have "TEST MESSAGE OR SOMETHING" you should have a string like:

```
To: someguy@gmail.com
From: myaddress@gmail.com
Subject: this is my cool subject

here's a text/plain email, neato?
```

remember to have `\r\n` between lines and two between headers and body.  seems for php that [PEAR::Mail_Mime](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.example.php) is a good library for constructing such rfc822 MIME email message strings.

For more details, see [Sending Email](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending).